# exception when using boost::serialization with boost::asio

Tags: exception, boost-asio, boost-serialization

my server runs following code:

```
boost::asio::streambuf streambuf;
std::istream istream(&streambuf);
boost::archive::xml_iarchive xml_iarchive(istream);
boost::asio::read_until(socket_, streambuf, '\n');
```

When the server is up and running I connect vie telnet from another machine. Immediately after connection is established, the connection is getting closed and the server crashes with following exception:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::archive::xml_archive_exception'
    what():  unrecognized XML syntax
```

Where is the failure at the code snippet above? It looks to me that the telnet session is sending a '\n' before I manually enter some XML string.

Comment: which line throws the exception?

Comment: boost::archive::xml_iarchive xml_iarchive(istream);

Answer (score 4):

You didn't post a [sscce](http://sscce.org), so I created one for you

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/xml_iarchive.hpp>

int
main()
{
    try {
        boost::asio::streambuf streambuf;
        std::istream istream(&streambuf);
        boost::archive::xml_iarchive xml_iarchive(istream);
    } catch ( const std::exception& e ) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

As expected, an exception is throw from line 10:

```
samm$ ./a.out
unrecognized XML syntax
```

This has nothing to do with Boost.Asio, you're trying to deserialize an empty buffer, which isn't valid XML. To solve this, delay the deserialization until after reading from the socket into the buffer

```
boost::asio::read_until(socket_, streambuf, '\n');
std::istream istream(&streambuf);
boost::archive::xml_iarchive xml_iarchive(istream);
```